# changing the sign

Tags: scheme, racket

In scheme I have the code

```
(* -1(expt -1 k)
```

which alternates the sign from `-` and `+`, I was just wondering if there was another way to do this without the exponent sign maybe with modulo possibly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(* -1 (expt -1 k))` will have the effect of becoming `-1` for odd values and `1` for even values of k. You can replace if with this:

```
(if (odd? k) -1 1)
```

The nice thing about this is spells out almost exactly what I explained the other actually does mathematically.

Also you don't need to do `(* -1 value)` to get the negative. It's enough to do `(- value)` which is short for `(- 0 value)`.

Comment: what does `odd?` do

Comment: @Joe `odd?` is a standard predicate procedure that returns `#t` if the number is odd eg. `1, 3, 5, 7, ...`

Comment: would you possibly know how you would do this with modulo, just wondering

Comment: You mean `(define (my-odd? v) (= (modulo v 2) 1)))` ? Know that `modulo` would need to do a division. A faster approach would be `(define (my-odd? v) (= (bitwise-and v 1) 1))`